# Как сделать листание картинок кликом на JS

Tags: javascript, слайдер

Я хотел бы сделать обычную "листалку" изображений, только без навигационных стрелок — я хочу, чтобы листание назад происходило при клике на левую половину изображения, а вперёд — при клике на правую.

Я написал такой код:

```
    <!-- Листалка -->
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Листалка</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<!-- Основной блок. Располагается по центру. Курсор имеет вид <—> -->
     <div style='text-align: center; cursor: e-resize;'>

<!-- Изображение -->
       <img id="image" src="1.jpg" onClick="imgsrc();"/>

     </div>

<!-- Скрипт -->
    <script language="javascript">

<!-- Переменная i показывает, какое по счёту изображение отображается на экране -->
        var i=1;

<!-- Вывод изображения -->
        var image=document.getElementById("image");
       document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = i;

   <!-- Массив с изображениями -->
        var imgs=new Array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '1.jpg');


   <!-- Ширина экрана-->
        var w = screen.width;

   <!--Местоположение курсора по оси x-->
        var p = clientX;

   <!-- Функция листания изображений -->
    function imgsrc() {

<!-- Если курсор ближе к правому краю экрана, изображения листаются вперёд -->
          if(p > (w / 2)){

       if (i < 3) {
            i++;
            image.src=imgs[i];  
            }

          else {
            i = 1;
              image.src=imgs[i];
              }
          }

<!-- Если курсор ближе к левому краю экрана, изображения листаются назад -->
      else{

              if (i > 1) {
            i = i - 1;
            image.src=imgs[i];
            }

          else {
            i = 3;
              image.src=imgs[i];
              }
          }
      }
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Однако этот код не работает, нормально: где бы я не шёлкнул по картинке, листание происходит назад.
В чём ошибка?

Comment: Посмотрите, что у вас хранится в переменной `p`, когда вы нажимаете на картинку. Думаю, что там `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере слишком много ошибок было.

В будущем открывайте консоль браузера, в хроме F12, очень удобная штука.

Посмотрите работающий пример кода.

```js
var imgs = new Array('https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/assets/showcase/images/logo.png', 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', 'https://material.io/tools/icons/static/ic_material_192px_light.svg');

var image = document.getElementById("image");

image.src = imgs[0];
image.dataset.current = 0;

function slide(ind) {
  let current = +image.dataset.current;
  current += ind;
  if (current >= imgs.length)
    current = 0;
  if (current < 0)
    current = imgs.length - 1;
  image.src = imgs[current];
  image.dataset.current = current;
}

function imgsrc(event) {
  var w = document.body.clientWidth;
  var p = event.clientX;
  if (p > (w / 2)) {
    slide(1);
  } else {
    slide(-1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style='text-align: center; cursor: e-resize;'>

  <img id="image" onclick="imgsrc(event);" />

</div>
```

Comment: хороший ответ лови плюсь

Comment: Спасибо. Это сработало

Comment: А как к такому слайдеру добавить анимацию?

Comment: @IliaLivshits Какую именно анимацию вы хотите?